# instead of echo message i am getting php file in wamp browser localhost

Tags: php, localhost, wampserver

As this is first time i am using the wamp server, i successfully managed to install and run the application and notification icon turns to green.I am able to access to localhost in browser. I tried to run php code in browser, but instead of executing it is showing the whole code.

initial.php

```
<?php
$db_name = "webappdb";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "root";
$server_name = "localhost";

$con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);

if(!$con) {
    echo"Connection Error...".mysqli_connect();
} else {
    echo"<h3>Database connection Success....</h3>";
}
?>
```

This file path is `C:\wamp64\www\webapp`, i created the `webapp` folder and `initial.php` is in `webapp` folder.

In browser i searched like this 
`localhost/webapp/initial.php`

Comment: check your post80 is available for apache and try with `127.0.0.1`

Comment: ya i checked and tried with 127.0.0.1 and it is working

Comment: No before asking this question, 127.0.0.1 is working. I didnt cleared my problem. I said it is working fine for 127.0.0.1

Comment: so still now you get source code instance of output right??

Comment: yes, now the thing is that my initial.php should execute and display echo message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128152/discussion-between-lifetimeprogrammer-and-praveen-kumar).

Comment: Most likely you forgot to add these 2 lines `127.0.0.1 localhost` and `::1 localhost` to your HOSTS file.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. The problem is with my password and server name.

```
<?php

$db_name="webappdb";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass="7500953495";
$server_name="127.0.0.1";

$con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);

if(!$con){
echo"Connection Error...".mysqli_connect();

}
else
{
echo"<h3>Database connection Success....</h3>";
}

?>
```

Before my server name is localhost and i changed it to 127.0.0.1

```
$server_name="localhost";
```

to

```
$server_name="127.0.0.1";
```

Comment: I bet you forgot to add these 2 lines `127.0.0.1 localhost` and `::1 localhost` to your HOSTS file. This will allow you to use the domain `localhost`